# Concatenate String in php

Tags: php

When i click on Add buttton it adds the dropdown selected text to the bottom textbox. and again when i change the value of dropdown and click on add. It rewrites the in textbox. I want to concatenate with previous value of the textbox with comma saparated whenever i click on add
Im new to php.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["in_submit"]))
{

    $i1=$_POST['name'];
    $i2=$_POST['dose'];
    $i3 = $i1."*".$i2;

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
    <select name="name" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
        <option value="Select">--SELECT--</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="def">def</option>                            
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="dose" value="" class="form-control"/>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="submit" name="in_submit" value="Add" class="btn-danger" style="height:30px;width:60px;padding-top:2px;border-radius:5px"/>
    </div>

</form>
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="<?php if(isset($i3)){ echo $i3;}?>" class="form-control" readonly  />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i suggest first to separate the php code and the html second the changes should be in the form

Answer (score 0):

Is because $i2=$_POST['dose']; is always empty

```
    value="<?php if(isset($i3)){ echo $i3;}?>"
```

should be part of dose

Answer (score 0):

```html
After some changes You don't need to use dose you can concatenate like this -> if you get the solution then vote up.
<?php

if(isset($_POST["in_submit"]))
{

    $i1=$_POST['name'];
 $i2=$_POST['text'];
if($i2!=''){
  
  $i3 = $i2.",".$i1;
}else{
  $i3 = $i1;
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
    <select name="name" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
        <option value="Select">--SELECT--</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="def">def</option>                            
    </select>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="submit" name="in_submit" value="Add" class="btn-danger" style="height:30px;width:60px;padding-top:2px;border-radius:5px"/>
    </div>
 <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="<?php if(isset($i3)){ echo $i3;}?>" class="form-control" readonly  />
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```